# How can I fix the error "404 requested resource is not found" when clicking the report accessible report link?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, msbi

I scheduled an SSRS report, report runs successfully as the email recipients receive the email but the link at the end of the email that says 'The report is accessible at the following address: link', throws an error:

> Not Found HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Can someone suggest why is this happening?

Comment: Sounds like its providing an incorrect link?

Comment: If you typed `link` into a web browser's location bar then where should it take you? If it's not actually `link` then what's the address behind it?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the actual URL provided in the email and compare that to what you see when you actually manully run a report. It will be different but there might be something obvious, perhaps an extra character.

Comment: @Nick.Mc Just checked, there are indeed a few extra characters. I copied the both links(the  link that was shared on the email along with the link that gets generated when I manually run the report ) to a notepad next to each other. So the problem is indeed that. I also checked the SSRS 'Subscriptions' under the 'Manage' section, but unable to figure out how the link is getting generated.

Comment: I don't have any more ideas except maybe the report name has some weird characters that cause a bug. It might help to edit the two different URL's into your question (with appropriate info replaced).